# Why do I get a segmentation fault? The code works fine in CLion and VSC

Tags: c, nested-loops, c-strings, function-definition, tolower

I am currently using exercism, to improve my programming skills. The code works fine in my IDE, but causes an error message on the website. What did I do wrong and how would you improve my code? Thx in advance :)

> make: *** [makefile:22: test] Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include "isogram.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool is_isogram(const char phrase[]) {
    int length = strlen(phrase);
    char temp[length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        temp [i] = phrase[i];

    temp[length] = '\0';

    for(int i = 0; temp[i]; i++){
        temp[i] = tolower(temp[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < length;j++) {
            if (temp[i] == temp[j] && temp[i] != ' ' && temp[i] != '-')
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    char phrase[] = "lumberjacks";
    if (is_isogram(phrase))
        printf("true");
    else
        printf("false");
    return 0;
}
```

I asked ChatGPT and it suggested the `temp[length] = '\0';` line, but this doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: `char temp[length + 1];` would allow space for the terminating 0. Why not convert to lowercase as you copy? No need for two loops. The last two loops look a bit odd, are you sure those loop conditions are correct? Can you provide a [mcve] that shows how you call it for both an expected true and false result?

Comment: As an example for why the loops at the bottom might not be correct. A lowercase a in ASCII has a value of 97. Do you really want to iterate from 0 to 96 in the outer loop in that case?

Comment: A small nitpick: your array is too short to accommodate the null terminator, _but_ you never use your array as a C string that needs to be null-terminated. You could leave that out and use the length as a bound in your loops, rather than testing if `temp[i]` is true.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh I missed that seems like chatgpt changed them. I wanted to use i < length as condition. I used these words as tests: lumberjacks, background, downstream, Isograms.

Comment: If you have a `char arr[length];` (with inclusive bounds from 0 to `length - 1`), then accessing `arr[length]` is out of bounds. The comments regarding the null terminator are correct, and you can still use `i < length`, since you presumably don't want to overwrite the null terminator. Even still, these are VLAs and I'd discourage their use over `malloc` unless you intended to do so.

Comment: *The code works fine in CLion and VSC*  Not blowing up is not "working fine".  As far as *I asked ChatGPT and it suggested the `temp[length] = '\0';`*?  ChatGPT is a f!*&^#!@ **STUPID** regurgitation machine that vomits out whatever garbage it's been crammed with.  C arrays are zero based, so if `length` is the size of the `temp` array, `temp[length]` is out-of-bounds.  And ChatGPT is literally too **STUPID** to realize that.  There's zero "intelligence" behind ChatGPT.

Comment: ChatGPT can tell nice bedtime stories but it cannot debug your program. It does not understand what it says, it just matches words.

Answer (score 0):

For starters using the variable length array

```
int length = strlen(phrase);
char temp[length];
```

is unsafe and redundant. Pay attention to that the return type of the function `strlen` is the unsigned type `size_t` not the signed type `int`.

Also calling the function `strlen` is redundant. You can scan a string based on the fact that it is terminated by the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

You defined an array that does not have a room for the terminating zero character `'\0'`. As a result this assignment

```
temp[length] = '\0';
```

invokes undefined behavior.

To convert all characters of the variable length array before checking whether the string is isogram

```
for(int i = 0; temp[i]; i++){
    temp[i] = tolower(temp[i]);
}
```

is inefficient.

Words in a phrase can be separated not only by the space character `' '` but also by the tab character `'\t'`. Also you should exclude punctuations.

I would write the function the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_isogram( const char phrase[] )
{
    bool isogram = true;

    if (*phrase != '\0')
    {
        for (const char *current = phrase + 1; isogram && *current != '\0'; ++current)
        {
            if (!isblank( ( unsigned char )*current ) && !ispunct( ( unsigned char )*current ))
            {
                char c = tolower( ( unsigned char )*current );

                const char *prev = current;

                while (isogram && prev != phrase)
                {
                    --prev;
                    isogram = tolower( ( unsigned char )*prev ) != c;
                }
            }
        }
    }  

    return isogram;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *phrase = "lumberjacks";

    printf( "The phrase \"%s\" is isogram: %s\n",
        phrase, is_isogram( phrase ) ? "true" : "false" );
}
```

The program output is

```
The phrase "lumberjacks" is isogram: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Vlad from Moscow has nicely pointed out the issues with your array length, but as he notes, the array you're using is unecessary. An O(n) solution this problem might involve creating a histogram: we're going to count each letter using a 26 element array where each element corresponds to a letter of the English alphabet. This can then be checked in one iteration to ensure no letter occurs more than once (or that every letter occurs the same number of times).

We could be potentially more efficient by doing this in one function, but this demonstrates how a program can be broken down into smaller problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int *alpha_histogram(const char *str) {
    int *hist = calloc(sizeof(int), 26);
    if (!hist) return NULL;

    for (const char *ch = str; *ch; ch++) {
         if (!isalpha(*ch)) continue;

         hist[tolower(*ch) - 'a']++;
    }

    return hist;
}

bool is_isogram(const char *str) {
    int *hist = alpha_histogram(str);
    if (!hist) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
         if (hist[i] > 1) return false;
    }

    free(hist);

    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *str = "lumberjacks";

    if (is_isogram(str)) {
        printf("\"%s\" is an isogram.\n", str);
    }
}
```